# Fish equivalent to for loop with evaluation

Tags: fish

How would you write the equivalent script in **fish**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls`
do
  echo $i
done
```

Thank you

Comment: Note that in bash, you should write `for i in *; do echo "$i"; done` to properly handle filenames with whitespace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fish uses `(` parens `)` rather than backticks for capturing shell output:

```
for i in (ls)
  echo $i
end
```